# iPhone application Info.plist language property

Tags: iphone, plist, itunes-store

Which property should I change on Info.plist in order to configure the list of languages shown in itunes store under my submitted application?

EDIT: My application will be in Greek and I want to see Greek as the only language under Languages in the App Store. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the "Localization native development region" value on the .plist file is related to the languages that appear on the app store after Languages.

Answer (score 0):

What you list in the plist does not affect what is shown in iTunes.  When you submit to itunesconnect, you will be asked to enter languages that are supported.  Of course , you will want to match these languages up with what your app really can support, but iTunes will not just show the supported languages by default.

EDIT:
It appears the OP is just asking how to localize within the app.  See [here](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/10/tutorial-part-2-localizing-your-iphone-application/)

Comment: I was reading the iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide and this is what it says: "The primary language you select here will not display in the App Store under Languages. The information that displays on the App Store is set in your binary." Here being the Primary Language Setting on iTunes Connect, which I think is the language of the app's metadata. So how do I set in my binary?

Comment: I amended my answer with a link to a localization tutorial

Comment: I am not trying to have different languages on my app. I just want to have one, different than English. See my edited question.

Comment: Actually adding the languages in iTunes Connect, perhaps unintuitively, won't add them to the iTunes Store near the app as the OP asked. It will create localized descriptions, titles and screenshots, but your app will still only show as "supporting English" this way.

Comment: "The list of languages displayed in the App Store under Languages is set in the app binary." From here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html

Comment: @DannyParker That only refers the the short list, not the localized description, tags, images or anything else. You have to manually add those for each language you support.

Comment: The question specifically refers to the plist, and the plist setting determines what is displayed in the 'Languages' section on the app store. Adding localised descriptions, images, etc. does not have any impact on what the App Store shows under the 'Languages' section as per the link.

Comment: It did 3+ years ago when this was answered.